Entangled Photons passing different polarizers
Consider two entangled photons leaving a source. Both are polarized at angle 0. One travels to the left and the other to the right. The one on the left encounters a polarizer at 30 degrees and the one on the right encounters a polarizer at angle 60 degrees.
What is the probability of both photons passing their polarizers?
According to Malus, the probability of passing the polarizer is $cos^2(\Theta)$.
If the photons are not entangled, then it is just $cos^2(30).cos^2(60)$, which is $\frac{3}{16}$.
If they are entangled, my math goes like this:
If the left photon passes its 30 degree polarizer first, then the right photon assumes a polarization of 30 degrees, so its probability of passing the 60 degree polarizer becomes $cos^2(60-30)$. So the probability of both passing becomes $cos^2(30).cos^2(60-30)$, which is $\frac{9}{16}$.
If the right photon passes its 60 degree polarizer first, then the left photon assumes a polarization of 60 degrees, so its probability of passing the 30 degree polarizer becomes $cos^2(30-60)$. So the probability of both passing becomes $cos^2(60).cos^2(30-60)$, which is $\frac{3}{16}$.
Since these are different, it depends on which photon passes its polarizer first. That seems odd. Where did I go wrong?

"If the left photon passes its 30 degree polarizer first, then the right photon assumes a polarization of 30 degrees" --- You can't possibly know this without a whole lot more information about the initial state beyond just "it's entangled".

Just a reminder: entangled or not, order   Of measurement makes no difference.
Your arithmetic is off because you started with the idea the first photon passed. You must also consider the case it does not pass. There are 4 total permutations. Once you adjust for that, there will be no difference.

If I shine a 405nm laser at a single BBO crystal (not paired), I will get two entangled beams at 810nm with equal and known polarization. No? If two of these entangled photons hit a 45 degree polarizer the probability of passing is 1/2, but their passing is correlated: either both pass or both block. What happens if one polarizer is 30 degrees and the other 60?

The problem is that you said the photons were entangled but you assumed that the angle between the photons and the first polarizer (on either side) was fixed. In truth, if you have an entangled state, you expect some indefiniteness for that angle (because you don't know a priori at what angle the photons are).
In math, you want an entangled state like
$$(|0\rangle|0\rangle-|90\rangle|90\rangle)/\sqrt{2},$$ where there is an equal probability for finding both photons at angle 0 versus angle 90 degrees, and similarly for any other pair of orthogonal directions. This is the state that has the property that projecting one particle onto some state $|\theta\rangle$ automatically projects the other onto the same state $|\theta\rangle$.
The overall probability from Malus's law must take into account both branches of the wavefunction, while the calculation in the question only took into account the $|0\rangle |0\rangle$ branch for the first polarizer encountered, then assumed the second particle was projected onto some state. In truth, with only the state $|0\rangle |0\rangle$, there is no entanglement and one would expect no correlations between any behaviours of the two particles.

I am asking about two photons of known polarization that are entangled. Suppose the initial polarization is 0 degrees. If they both hit a polarizer at 45 degrees, the probability of passing is 1/2. The entanglement ensures that they either both pass or both block. If they are not entangled, it is possible for one to pass and the other to block. My question is what happens when one of these photons hits a 30 degree polarizer and the other hits a 60 degree polarizer.

@JakobHeitz if the photons have known polarization then they are not entangled! At least, they are not entangled in the polarization degree of freedom. And if they are not entangled in the polarization degree of freedom, then whatever happens to one photon at one polarizer has zero bearing on what happens to the other photon at another polarizer


Since these are different, it depends on which photon passes its
polarizer first. That seems odd. Where did I go wrong?

What you are missing is that the probability of a randomly orientated photon passing through a single polariser is 50%. When the entangled photons are prepared we do not know their orientation and if we measure their orientation we alter its state and break the entanglement. Even though it is possible that one pair of entangled photons have 0 orientation, entanglement correlation experiments are usually the the result of hundreds of measurements as you can not get a correlation relationship  from a single measurement. This means that if the photon on the left passes through a polariser first the combined probability for both photons is $ 0.5\times cos^2(60-30) = 3/8$. If the photon on the right passes through a polariser first the combined probability for both photons is $ 0.5\times cos^2(30-60) = 3/8$. The result is independent of which photon arrived first. The surprising conclusion is that the probability of a pair of entangled photons separately passing through a pair of polarising filters is the same as a the probability of a single photon passing through the two filters in succession.

In this diagram the "unpolarised incident beam" is actually a collection of photons with random orientations, but each photon has  a definite but unknown polarisation.
